# Global search in ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, datatables, angular2-directives

Is there any way to achieve a global search with [ng2-smart-table](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/)? Note it is filtering by column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can what you are looking for can be found here:

https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/demo#separate-filter

Edit:

For some reason the page above doesn't load

go to the page you posted, then go to demos and do a ctrl + f and search for: Standalone Filter Example Scroll down and you will see the live demo :)

Comment: Sorry, it says "400 Bad Request"

Comment: Strange, go to the page you posted, then go to demos and do a ctrl + f and search for:
Standalone Filter Example

Scroll down and you will see the live demo :)